# Creating a titlepage: two figures in one line (left and right)

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

In order to create a title page I would like to include two logos in one line where one of the figures is left and the other is one the right side.

My first minimalistic examples using the following code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \flushleft
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.15\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{figure}
\hfill
\begin{figure}[h]
    \flushright
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.15\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{figure}
```

leads to the following output:

[image]

Both figures do have exactly the size and horizontal position I want them to have. They simply are not in one line ...

Adding to the code above the following:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \flushleft
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.25\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \flushright
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.25\linewidth]{test.png}
\end{minipage}
```

i get this:

[image]

At least in this case both logos are in one line but now the size is different as they are smaller and they are not in the same horizonal position they used to be in figure 1.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you dont want figure or minipage just `\includegraphics{a}\hfill\includegraphics{b}`

Comment: The size is different because in one case you use `0.15\linewidth` and on the other 50% of `0.25\linewidth` which is `0.125\linewidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `figure` or `minipage` just

```
\noindent
\includegraphics{a}\hfill\includegraphics{b}
```